# Creating a /var/run folder for a PID file, disappears on reboot?

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-14.04

I'm creating a folder in `/var/run` which will house my service's PID file:

```
file { 'service_pid_folder': 
    path   => '/var/run/myservice',
    ensure => directory,
    owner  => $user,
    group  => $group,
}
```

This runs without any problems. The strange thing is that when I reboot my machine and re-run `puppet apply`, it reruns the creation of this directory on every reboot.

On reboot, the directory doesn't exist, strangely enough. If I try creating it as my process user, I get permission denied.

Why does this folder disappear on reboot? My host is an Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#VARRUNRUNTIMEVARIABLEDATA):

> This directory contains system information data describing the system since it was booted. Files under this directory must be cleared (removed or truncated as appropriate) at the beginning of the boot process.

Your system seems to accomplish this by removing the whole tree (or backing it with a volatile filesystem), which I think is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Since my service runs as a non-root user, I'll just create run directories in a different place.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay it is the responsibility of the init (or whatever) script to create these subdirectories before dropping their privileges.

Comment: @FelixFrank great, but what if your script is running as a non-root user and you want users other than root to control stop/start?

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay make sure the script can `sudo` itself and does so if necessary. Enabeling unpriviliged users to perform this kinds of action without it is more trouble than it's worth - this has been my experience at least.